# Sobreposição de gráficos

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, chartjs

Tenho um problema quando crio um gráfico com o chart.js e em seguida faço para gerar outro gráfico a partir do menu que está na mesma página. Ele cria o gráfico, mas quando mexo o cursor pelo gráfico ele muda para o gráfico anterior.

**Update**

Após uma pesquisa na documentação do chartJS encontrei um suposto método que limpa a informação do gráfico com o `.removeData()`. Apliquei esse método no controlador, mas infelizmente continua a apresentar o grafico anterior no *background* quando passo o rato pelo gráfico. Também realizei um `console.log` no array que contem a informação e essa informação é atualizada com a informação do ultimo *request* enviado.

Código do controlador

```
 $scope.getChart = function (report) {
 $scope.modalLabels = [];
 $scope.data = {values: ([])}; //Array that contains the data recieved from the server
 if($('#chartBar')!=null){
    $('#chartBar').removeData();
  }
 /*Funçao para que obtém as informações por parte do servidor*/
 //Se receber informação
  var avgCapacity = [];
 for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++) {
  avgCapacity.push(data[i].Volume);
  $scope.modalLabels.push(data[i].Day + "/" + data[i].Month);
        }
  $scope.data.values = ([avgCapacity]);
```

Primeiro gráfico
[image: Primeiro gráfico]
Segundo gráfico
[image: Segundo gráfico]
Html que gera os graficos:

```
<div ng-hide="data==0">
    <h4 id="chartTitle"><b>{{Title}}</b></h4>
 <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" chart-data="data" chart-options="options"
    chart-labels="modalLabels" chart-legend="true" chart-series="series">
```

Comment: Tem o angular chart js, nele tem facilitadores para criar gráficos com angular sugiro dar uma olhada nele e tentar fazer o que você precisa. https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#reactive

Answer (score 2):

Passei pelo mesmo problema.

A solução foi que ao trocar os dados eu removia o canvas do DOM e inseria um novo canvas com os novos valores.

Ai criei uma diretiva que encapsulava as diretivas do [angular-chartjs](https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) e me adicionava dois métodos ao objeto passado a ela, o `create()` e `clear()`.

Ex:

```
<my-charts chart-model="vm.chart"></my-charts>
```

Ai essa diretiva tratava de criar e compilar todo o html adicionando os valores do objeto `vm.chart` e dando a ele o `create()` e `clear()`.

Ai quando precisava atualizar o chart fazia um `clear()`, atualizava os dados e dava um `create()`.

Eu fiz isso no meu antigo trabalho e infelizmente não tenho mais acesso ao código.